# Python tic-toc-toe ai doesn't choose the best move

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe, minmax

I have an tic-tac-toe game and i would like to add an ai to it. I also would like to use minmax so it always chooses the best move to win the game, i added the minmax formula but it doesn't work, it evaluate the all possible options but doens't use it, it just increases the col and row + 1 and continues like that. What am i doing wrong?

```
"""A tic-tac-toe game built with Python and Tkinter."""

import tkinter as tk
from itertools import cycle
from tkinter import font
from typing import NamedTuple
import pandas as pd
import copy

class Player(NamedTuple):
    label: str
    color: str

class Move(NamedTuple):
    row: int
    col: int
    label: str = ""

BOARD_SIZE = 3
DEFAULT_PLAYERS = (
    Player(label="X", color="blue"),
    Player(label="O", color="green"),
)

class TicTacToeGame:
    def __init__(self, players=DEFAULT_PLAYERS, board_size=BOARD_SIZE):
        self._players = cycle(players)
        self.board_size = board_size
        self.current_player = next(self._players)
        self.winner_combo = []
        self._current_moves = []
        self._has_winner = False
        self._winning_combos = []
        self._setup_board()

    def _setup_board(self):
        self._current_moves = [
            [Move(row, col) for col in range(self.board_size)]
            for row in range(self.board_size)
        ]
        self._winning_combos = self._get_winning_combos()

    def _get_winning_combos(self):
        rows = [
            [(move.row, move.col) for move in row]
            for row in self._current_moves
        ]
        columns = [list(col) for col in zip(*rows)]
        first_diagonal = [row[i] for i, row in enumerate(rows)]
        second_diagonal = [col[j] for j, col in enumerate(reversed(columns))]
        return rows + columns + [first_diagonal, second_diagonal]

    def toggle_player(self):
        """Return a toggled player."""
        self.current_player = next(self._players)

    def is_valid_move(self, move):
        """Return True if move is valid, and False otherwise."""
        row, col = move.row, move.col
        move_was_not_played = self._current_moves[row][col].label == ""
        no_winner = not self._has_winner
        return no_winner and move_was_not_played

    def process_move(self, move):
        """Process the current move and check if it's a win."""
        row, col = move.row, move.col
        self._current_moves[row][col] = move
        for combo in self._winning_combos:
            results = set(self._current_moves[n][m].label for n, m in combo)
            is_win = (len(results) == 1) and ("" not in results)
            if is_win:
                self._has_winner = True
                self.winner_combo = combo
                break

    def has_winner(self):
        """Return True if the game has a winner, and False otherwise."""
        return self._has_winner

    def is_tied(self):
        """Return True if the game is tied, and False otherwise."""
        no_winner = not self._has_winner
        played_moves = (
            move.label for row in self._current_moves for move in row
        )
        return no_winner and all(played_moves)

    def reset_game(self):
        """Reset the game state to play again."""
        for row, row_content in enumerate(self._current_moves):
            for col, _ in enumerate(row_content):
                row_content[col] = Move(row, col)
        self._has_winner = False
        self.winner_combo = []

    def get_possible_moves(self):
        possible_moves = []
        for row in range(self.board_size):
            for col in range(self.board_size):
                if self._current_moves[row][col].label == '':
                    possible_moves.append((row, col))
        print(possible_moves)
        return possible_moves   


class TicTacToeBoard(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, game):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Tic-Tac-Toe Game")
        self._cells = {}
        self._game = game
        self._create_menu()
        self._create_board_display()
        self._create_board_grid()

    def _create_menu(self):
        menu_bar = tk.Menu(master=self)
        self.config(menu=menu_bar)
        file_menu = tk.Menu(master=menu_bar)
        file_menu.add_command(label="Play Again", command=self.reset_board)
        file_menu.add_separator()
        file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)
        menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)

    def _create_board_display(self):
        display_frame = tk.Frame(master=self)
        display_frame.pack(fill=tk.X)
        self.display = tk.Label(
            master=display_frame,
            text="Ready?",
            font=font.Font(size=28, weight="bold"),
        )
        self.display.pack()

    def _create_board_grid(self):
        grid_frame = tk.Frame(master=self)
        grid_frame.pack()
        for row in range(self._game.board_size):
            self.rowconfigure(row, weight=1, minsize=50)
            self.columnconfigure(row, weight=1, minsize=75)
            for col in range(self._game.board_size):
                button = tk.Button(
                    master=grid_frame,
                    text="",
                    font=font.Font(size=36, weight="bold"),
                    fg="black",
                    width=3,
                    height=2,
                    highlightbackground="lightblue",
                )
                self._cells[button] = (row, col)
                button.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.play)
                button.grid(row=row, column=col, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="nsew")
    
    def minimax(self, is_ai):
        if self._game.has_winner():
            if self._game.current_player.label == 'O':  # AI is the winner
                return 10, None
            else:  # Human is the winner
                return -10, None
        elif self._game.is_tied():
            return 0, None

        best_score = -1000 if is_ai else 1000
        best_move = None

        for row, col in self._game.get_possible_moves():
            move = Move(row, col, self._game.current_player.label)
            self._game._current_moves[row][col] = move
            self._game.process_move(move)
            score, _ = self.minimax(not is_ai)
            self._game._current_moves[row][col] = Move(row, col)
            self._game._has_winner = False

            if is_ai and score > best_score:
                best_score = score
                best_move = (row, col)
            elif not is_ai and score < best_score:
                best_score = score
                best_move = (row, col)

        return best_score, best_move

      
    def ai_play(self):
        _, (row, col) = self.minimax(True)
        move = Move(row, col, self._game.current_player.label)
        if self._game.is_valid_move(move):
            self._game.process_move(move)
            for button, (button_row, button_col) in self._cells.items():
                if button_row == row and button_col == col:
                    self._update_button(button)
            if self._game.is_tied():
                self._update_display(msg="Tied game!", color="red")
            elif self._game.has_winner():
                self._highlight_cells()
                msg = f'Player "{self._game.current_player.label}" won!'
                color = self._game.current_player.color
                self._update_display(msg, color)
            else:
                self._game.toggle_player()
                msg = f"{self._game.current_player.label}'s turn"
                self._update_display(msg)
                
    
    
    def play(self, event):
        """Handle a player's move."""
        clicked_btn = event.widget
        row, col = self._cells[clicked_btn]
        move = Move(row, col, self._game.current_player.label)
        if self._game.is_valid_move(move):
            self._update_button(clicked_btn)
            self._game.process_move(move)
            if self._game.is_tied():
                self._update_display(msg="Tied game!", color="red")
            elif self._game.has_winner():
                self._highlight_cells()
                msg = f'Player "{self._game.current_player.label}" won!'
                color = self._game.current_player.color
                self._update_display(msg, color)
            else:
                self._game.toggle_player()
                msg = f"{self._game.current_player.label}'s turn"
                self._update_display(msg)
                self.ai_play()

    def _update_button(self, clicked_btn):
        clicked_btn.config(text=self._game.current_player.label)
        clicked_btn.config(fg=self._game.current_player.color)

    def _update_display(self, msg, color="black"):
        self.display["text"] = msg
        self.display["fg"] = color

    def _highlight_cells(self):
        for button, coordinates in self._cells.items():
            if coordinates in self._game.winner_combo:
                button.config(highlightbackground="red")

    def reset_board(self):
        """Reset the game's board to play again."""
        self._game.reset_game()
        self._update_display(msg="Ready?")
        for button in self._cells.keys():
            button.config(highlightbackground="lightblue")
            button.config(text="")
            button.config(fg="black")

def main():
    """Create the game's board and run its main loop."""
    game = TicTacToeGame()
    board = TicTacToeBoard(game)
    board.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried to apply many minmax formulas but this was the only code that i am was able run the script.

Comment: Your algorithm values "moves that could possibly end in a computer win" higher than "moves that definitely result in a player win", so it never defends itself.  You can't play tic-tac-toe this way.  You need to play like a human. (1) Can I win this time?  (2) Do I need to block an X win in the next move?  (3) Is there a move I can make that results in a win next time? (4) If none of the above, pick randomly.

Comment: Think about the board `[X O -], [- X -], [- - -]`.  Your algorithm thinks "if I move upper right, I can eventually win along the right edge", so it choose that move, even though the human will win on its next move.